# How to get the nine cycles without trial and error?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Determine the nine cycles that occur in sequences of natural numbers where each succeeding term is the sum of the cubes of the digits of the previous number.

My approach is to try one-by-one starting from 1, 2, 3, ....

1, $1^3=1$, so 1 is a cycle of order 1.
2, $2^3=8$, $8^3=64$, $6^3+4^3=280$, $2^3+8^3+0^3=520$, $5^3+2^3+0^3=133$, $1^3+3^3+3^3=55$, $5^3+5^3=250$, $2^3+5^3+0^3=133$, so 133, 55, 250 is another cycle of order 3.

I can try to continue the trial one-by-one and surely I can get those 9 cycles. But my question is is there any more efficient method to determine those 9 cycles or any better way to think about this problem?

Thank you for the helps!

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. However, without knowing that there are nine cycles, I don't see how you'd know when to stop in the cases which don't belong to a cycle.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to pull this off without some form of checking; this kind of problem feels similar to for instance the Collatz/Hailstone thing, though here at least you can take advantage of structure: you can guarantee, once you get above a certain size, that the next value generated will always be below what you've got.

Comment: that size isn't that high, either: $1999 \rightarrow 2188$ appears to be the highest number that goes up.

Comment: Note that because all but a finite number of positive integers reduce, every initial value will end stationary or in a loop. Cubing digits and adding preserves the residue class modulo $3$ so there will be at least three different outcomes, one for each residue class.